# Oracle APEX simple crud database app

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

I am very new to oracle pl/sql and APEX and not familiar yet to it.

I want to make a simple **CRUD** project using the Oracle's **Application Express** : https://apex.oracle.com/en/ , but unfortunately I could not find any example or documentation. I got some courses but the versions of apex differ and a lot of things have been changed so I am not able to implement what I need.

I have created a simple new table just for practice in the following way:
Sql Workshop -> Object Browser -> Create Table

And I have a very simple table: `New_Table` with fields: `id (INTEGER), name(VARCHAR2)`

Now I want to make a simple crud website for this table, but cannot understand how the forms work.

I created a database project: `App Builder -> Database Applications -> Create` and got a simple web project with a blank page.

**Questions:**

1. How can I create the form and bind it to the table?
2. If I understand correctly, for editing a record, I should pass the id to the next page, how can I do it? or how to implement the edit page?
3. How can I get the data from form fields, validate it and execute an sql query using that data?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you tried following [the official Oracle Apex tutorial](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/devdays2012/apexp1_lab/apexp1_lab.html)?

Comment: the problem is that it's not apex5. I think it's apex4. I cannot find a lot of things from the tutorial in apex5. For e.g creating a new region does not show which type of region I want to use it just creates the region, and in the settings I can choose static content, which is the most appropriate for forms (there is also report but I think it's not related to forms)

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way to start is to click **Create Page**, choose **Form**, then **Form on a Table with Report**. Follow the wizard to select your table and columns, and viola.

It will create two pages - a report page and a single-record edit page, with navigation links between them. You can then examine the regions, items, buttons and page processes on these pages to learn how they work.

Comment: thank you very much! And how can I validate the data from the field?